# Removing characters with button

Tags: iphone

i create a custom backspace button but my problem is my back button works great in order to delete character from middle of words but just remove 1 character after that (removing letters) , comes back to the end of line it means doesn't stay where the cursor is, here is my code :

```
        NSRange deleteRange = textPad.selectedRange;

        if (deleteRange.length >0)
        textPad.text = [textPad.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:deleteRange withString:@""];


        else

            if (deleteRange.location > 0)
            textPad.text =  [textPad.text  stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(deleteRange.location-1,1) 
 withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3):

i fixed it : just add this codes :

```
deleteRange.location--;
deleteRange.length = 0;
textPad.selectedRange = deleteRange;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem easily by setting the selectedRange property of the UITextView

```
    NSRange ran= textView.selectedRange
    //do your deletions
    ran.lenght=0;
  if(ran.location!=0)
    ran.location--;
    textView.selectedRange=ran;
```

Comment: looks like you found it by yourself anyway :)